# Question about proper queries

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table `author` with 4 columns (id, name, email, password)

```
CREATE TABLE author (
    id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    name VARCHAR(255),
    email VARCHAR(255),
    password CHAR(32),
    UNIQUE (email)
) DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8;
```

In my php, I am trying to run a query to grab the `id` from `author` then another query to insert it in  table `article`, under `authorid`.

**SQL :**

```
CREATE TABLE article (
   id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
   articletext TEXT,
   articledate DATE NOT NULL,
   authorid INT NOT NULL

) DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8;
```

**index.php :**

```
<?php
include_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] .
        '/includes/magicquotes.inc.php';
include $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . 
        '/includes/access.inc.php';

if (isset($_GET['add']))
  if (!userIsLoggedIn())
{
      include $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/includes/login.inc.html.php';
      exit();
}
  else
{
    $pagetitle = 'New Article';
    $action = 'addform';
    $text = '';
    $authorid = '';
    $id = '';
    $button = 'Add article';

    include 'form.html.php';
    exit();
}
if (isset($_GET['addform']))
{
    include $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/includes/db.inc.php';


    $text = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['text']);
    $authorid = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_SESSION['id']);

    $sql = "INSERT INTO article SET
            articletext='$text',
            articledate=CURDATE(),
            authorid= '$authorid'";
    if (!mysqli_query($link, $sql))
    {
        $error = 'Error adding submitted article: ' . mysqli_error($link);
        include 'error.html.php';
        exit();
    }

    header('Location: .');
    exit();
}
include $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/includes/db.inc.php';

$result = mysqli_query($link, 'SELECT id, articletext FROM article');
if (!$result)
{
    $error = 'Error fetching articles: ' . mysqli_error($link);
    include 'error.html.php';
    exit();
}

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
    $articles[] = array('id' => $row['id'], 'text' => $row['articletext']);
}

include 'articles.html.php';
?>
```

**access.inc.php :**

```
<?php
function userIsLoggedIn()
{
    if (isset($_POST['action']) and $_POST['action'] == 'login')
    {
        if (!isset($_POST['email']) or $_POST['email'] == '' or
            !isset($_POST['password']) or $_POST['password'] == '')
        {
            $GLOBALS['loginError'] = 'Please fill in both fields';
            return FALSE;
        }
        $password = md5($_POST['password'] . 'chainfire db');
        if (databaseContainsAuthor($_POST['email'], $password))
        {   
        include 'db.inc.php';
            session_start();
            $_SESSION['loggedIn'] = TRUE;
            $_SESSION['email'] = $_POST['email']; 

            $sql = "SELECT id FROM author 
                    WHERE email = '{$_SESSION['email']}'";

            $result = mysqli_query($link, $sql);
            $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);

            $_SESSION['id'] = $row['id'];
            $_SESSION['password'] = $password;
            return TRUE;
        }
        else
        {
            session_start();
            unset($_SESSION['loggedIn']);
            unset($_SESSION['email']);
            unset($_SESSION['id']);
            unset($_SESSION['password']);
            $GLOBALS['loginError'] = 'The specified email address or password was incorrect.';
            return FALSE;
        }
    }
    if (isset($_POST['action']) and $_POST['action'] == 'logout')
    {
        session_start();
        unset($_SESSION['loggedIn']);
        unset($_SESSION['email']);
        unset($_SESSION['id']);
        unset($_SESSION['password']);
        header('Location: ' . $_POST['goto']);
        exit();
    }
    session_start();
    if (isset($_SESSION['loggedIn']))
    {
        return databaseContainsAuthor($_SESSION['email'], $_SESSION['password']);
    }
}
function databaseContainsAuthor($email, $password)
{
    include 'db.inc.php';

    $email = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $email);
    $password = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $password);

    $sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM author
            WHERE email='$email' AND password='$password'";
    $result = mysqli_query($link, $sql);

    if (!$result)
    {
        $error = 'Error searching for author.';
        include 'error.html.php';
        exit();
    }
    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
    if ($row[0] > 0)
    {
        return TRUE;
    }
    else
    {
        return FALSE;
    }
}
function userHasRole($role)
{
    include 'db.inc.php';

    $email = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_SESSION['email']);
    $role = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $role);

    $sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM author
            INNER JOIN authorrole ON author.id = authorid
            INNER JOIN role ON roleid = role.id
            WHERE email = '$email' AND role.id='$role'";

    $result = mysqli_query($link, $sql);
    if (!$result)
    {
        $error = 'Error searching for author roles.';
        include 'error.html.php';
        exit();
    }
    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);

    if ($row[0] > 0)
    {
        return TRUE;
    }
    else
    {
        return FALSE;
    }
}

?>
```

I left some of the code out, I can't get the `authorid` column in `article` table to return anything but 0.  I am wondering if this has something to do with the fact that `id` column in the `author` table has a `PRIMARY KEY` attribute as well as the `email` column which I have set to `UNIQUE`.  Should I be running different queries that better reference columns with `PRIMARY KEY` and `UNIQUE` attributes?

Comment: There are many problems with your code, but they are mistakes of logic (i.e. not thinking through the interaction between your user and the website, not understanding the functions), and of security, not problems with the database.

Answer (score 2):

`mysqli_query` returns a result resource (a pointer to the result set buffer in memory).

That's what you assigned to `$id`.

You have to fetch the row(s) from that result, and use the desired column of each row.

```
$sql = "SELECT id FROM author 
        WHERE email = '{$_SESSION['email']}'";

$result = mysqli_query($link, $sql);
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
$_SESSION['id'] = $row['id'];
```

Comment: There's also a whole bunch of logic errors. There's a good possibility `$_SESSION['id']` will not be defined when used in the last query.

Comment: Yes I guess that's the case since I'm still getting 0 in `authorid`.  It might make more sense if I update the op with all of my source code if you guys don't mind.  Thanks for the input, I'm still learning the ins and outs of PHP & MySQL.